# Selenium IE - No Such Window Exception (Debugging is working however)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

as per the title, I am using Selenium 2.45.0 WebDriver and trying to run some tests in IE11 with Win7 Pro. I have used these in Firefox and all works well.

The issue I am having is that shortly after the IE window is opened, Selenium looses track if it.  I have searched and found the registry key and tried the security settings.

Here's where it gets odd.  If I run this in Debug, it works.  No issues.  Just works.  I also, for a time, thought the firewall was blocking stuff as things passed the first time it ran ( an allow access window appeared) however after allowing access the tests fail.

Anyone have any extra ideas?

Comment: Is it happening after clicking a link or element which triggers a new window?

Comment: It seems to happen just after the window is created - and before I try to navigate to a URL (using the driver.get() method.

Comment: How are you instantiating the driver?

Comment: It goes through a class, but here's the important bit: `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "resources/IExploreDriver/2.45.0-32bit/IEDriverServer.exe");`
   
`driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working.  Initially, I had saw Issue 6511 on the selenium group and had set my registry key for the 32 bit version of IE - however according to the issue, I should have set my registry key based on the version of windows.  So 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE - added a DWORD called "iexplore.exe" and set it be 0.